# import/view table from external site

Tags: query, table

Good morning

I state that I am a novice user and I would kindly look for someone to help me solve the following problem:

I would like to know if it was possible to view directly on a page c/o menu of my wordpress site the 2 tables (results and ranking) that are displayed on the following page

http://www.fipavpiacenza.it/risultati-classifiche.aspx?ComitatoId=74&StId=1981&DataDa=&StatoGara=&CId=64620&SId=3942&PId=9653&btFiltro=CERCA

I think that the above aspx page is generated by a request via a server side script and I stress that I have no access to the site database or anything else.

I would like the page of my site to display only the 2 tables with nothing else around

and that it would automatically update based on the progress of the selected championship.

Sorry for the long post but I wanted to be as clear as possible…

Thanks for your help and have a nice day

Comment: what you're asking to do is a form of web scraping, you can split this question/problem into two parts, how to scrape the table off the site without the rest of it, and another question which is how to take something you've scraped and embed it in a post or page. The more stuff you bundle up into a single question, the less likely you'll get an answer, and the lower quality those answers will be

Comment: note that including the filtes/controls and requiring that it auto-update make this question much harder. If you didn't need those and were willing to copy just the tables you could literally select, right click copy, then paste it into a page